# How to create ember 2.8.0 project

Tags: node.js, npm, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to create a ember 2.8.0 project.

Ember.js docs doesn't help me in creating a version specific project. : (

A few questions were asked in stackoverflow regarding this topic and those answers were not working as none of them are accepted answers.

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Install the appropriate version of ember-cli and use it. One question though: why create a new project using code that is no longer supported?

Comment: I can't find the appropriate version of ember-cli. I tried all way ember-cli@2.0.0 to 2.8.0, but nothing worked. And a lot of deprecation warnings. Can you tell me the correct version of ember-cli for the ember 2.8.0 project.

I'm creating this project for developing components for a similar older ember project.

Comment: Why create even _more_ legacy work that needs to be upgraded? Create your addon in latest ember and use the 2.8 version in your ember-try tests ensure compatibility. At minimum, use the most recent ember 2 version, 2.18, rather than 2.8, to limit some work you need to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to create an Ember project with an old version:

1. Install that specific version globally.
2. Use `npx` to run `ember-cli` with that version once.

I would recommend the second option as having an outdated Ember CLI version installed globally could get confusing.

The command looks like this:

```
npx ember-cli@<version> new <application-name>
```

Using latest `v2.8` release and calling the application `my-app` the command looks like this:

```
npx ember-cli@~2.8.0 new my-app
```

You could set any options that you like.  For example if you want to use yarn as package manager you could run it like:

```
npx ember-cli@~2.8.0 new my-app --yarn
```